# How to fix 'Chrome Headless 115.0.5790.110 (Windows10) ERROR | Disconnected, because no message in 10000ms' error while trying to run karma unit test?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

We have a project with Angular15 and used Jasmine and Karma for uniting.
While we executing the test case we are getting the error as per the image below. Some time its run properly but maximum time showing the error. We have not found any solution for this problem.

Has anyone else come across this and possibly found a solution?
[Chrome Headless 115.0.5790.110 (Windows 10) ERROR
Disconnected , because no message in 1000000 ms.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvbap.png)

Our karma.conf.js :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['parallel', 'jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-parallel'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
    ],
    parallelOptions: {
      executors: 4, // Defaults to cpu-count - 1
      shardStrategy: 'round-robin'
    },
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      },
      captureConsole: false
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type : 'lcovonly'}
      ]
    },
    
    reporters: ["spec"],
    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5,             // limit number of lines logged per test
      suppressSummary: false,      // do not print summary
      suppressErrorSummary: false, // do not print error summary
      suppressFailed: false,      // do not print information about failed tests
      suppressPassed: false,      // do not print information about passed tests
      suppressSkipped: true,      // do not print information about skipped tests
      showBrowser: false,         // print the browser for each spec
      showSpecTiming: true,      // print the time elapsed for each spec
      failFast: false             // test would finish with error when a first fail occurs
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DISABLE,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 1000000
  });
};
```

Our test.ts:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
  { teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }},
);
```

jasmine/karma packages in package.json:

```
"@types/jasmine": "^4.3.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.10.1",
"karma": "~6.3.9",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
"karma-parallel": "^0.3.1"
```

Has anyone else come across this and possibly found a solution?

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Did you find out any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and was able to correct it by removing the following from the test.js file.

```
// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare 
it as any.
```

declare const **karma**: any;
declare const require: any;

```
 // Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
  __karma__.loaded = function () {};

 // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.

 // Then we find all the tests.
  const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
 // And load the modules.
  context.keys().map(context);
 // Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
 __karma__.start();
```